# Export images from formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has a column generating images (barcodes in this case) based off of data from other cells via the `=image(url)` function. I thought this would be a great way to quickly create the hundreds of barcodes I need instead of manually creating one at a time.

The barcodes generate perfectly (using barcodesinc.com URL-based calls), but there seems to be no way to export those images. There isn't an option to right-click to save the image, nor does copy/paste seem to work.

Are images generated from `=image(url)` useless besides visual presentation? Perhaps I'll need to create a script to accomplish something like this...

**Update:** I've also tried the Download As > Web page command, but as others have found out, the `=image(url)` function doesn't place the returned images in the resources folder. I believe only images place via Insert > Image do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `HYPERLINK` function. Then you can click the image, and see it in a new tab. For the you tab you can save / download / export or whatever you want.

[image]

Example Function

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/7650580-3x2-340x227.jpg",IMAGE("http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/7650580-3x2-340x227.jpg"))
```

Comment: Ha, I JUST thought of that. It might have to do for now, but hopefully there would be a quicker way to download 100+ images. Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways. But this is another question.
For example, you can copy all the images URLS into 1 text file, and use WGET: http://superuser.com/a/168625/185370